# My function returns an error 'Error: Unbound value '

Tags: ocaml

I need to return a copy of a list in which odd-length lists have been doubled (and only with these predefined functions `List.hd`, `List.tl` or `List.length`)

```
oddList [[]; [1];[1;2];[1;2;3];[];[5;4;3;2;1]]
```

must return

```
oddList [[]; [1; 1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 3]; []; [5; 4; 3; 2; 1; 5; 4; 3; 2; 1]]
```

When I test my function, it returns : "Error: Unbound value oddList" I don't know what's wrong

```
let rec oddList l =
  if l = [] then []
  else
    let fst = list.hd l in
    let rest = list.tl l in
    if length fst mod 2 = 0 then (fist :: (oddList rest))
    else ((fst@fst):: (oddList rest));;
```

Comment: I don't get that error, but I do get `Error: Unbound value list` due to `list.hd` and `list.tl` vs `List.hd` and `List.tl`. Module names always begin with uppercase letters.

Comment: Please do not tag irrelevant tags like in this case ocamlbuild, ocamllex, ocaml-dune, and ocamlyacc.

Comment: You also have a typo with `fist :: (oddList rest)`

Comment: You haven't qualified the name `length` with `List.`. Fix all of these issues and your code works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, it's very kind, but after these changes the problem remains

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please copy and paste from your interactive interpreter session showing this issue.

Comment: Again, please edit your question to show a top-level session that produces this error, or if you're compiling a file or files, please show us *all* of your code.

Answer (score 0):

There's no predefined function `length` in OCaml, but there is `List.length`.

(When posting problems like this to StackOverflow you should include the exact compiler error message, and indicate where in your program it is pointing to.)